# symfony2 - Mongodb date field form element - custom date range

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I have a simple mongodb document in a symfony2 app.  One of the properties is:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Date
 */
protected $dob;
```

However when adding it to the form like this:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('dob', 'date')
        ;
    }
```

I get a form element with 3 select boxes - one for year, month and day.  I would really like to have a text input for year and keep the select boxes for month and day.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom form field type. This [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) tells you how do that.